# BigQuery group by maximum value in one field while selecting distinct rows

Tags: google-bigquery

For every 20 minute period interval, I am trying to find the maximum value of bandwidth (column `mbps` in the table below), each of the unique IP addresses generates, with the corresponding port number.

Each IP address may or may not show up more than once in each 20-minute period. Each time an IP address gets recorded in the 20-minute period interval, it may or may not have the same port number listed.

For example, in the table below, the ip address 192.168.10.1 shows up three times during the period listed as 12:20, with port numbers 443, 80 and 80 respectively. In another scenario, the ip address 192.168.10.2 shows up twice during the period 12:40, with the same port number 443, listed twice, but with different values for the mbps (bandwidth) column.

The goal is to select and list each unique ip address only once, for each of the twenty minute period, sorting by mbps in DESC order.

The table is partitioned, based on the time of data injection.

I am planning to write a cron job, to automate this query. The cron job will run every hour, 7 days a week. The query is to be in standard SQL.

original table:

```
Row time                ip_address          port        mbps

1   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.1        443         100
2   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.1        80          120
3   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.2        80          200
4   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.1        80          110
5   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.2        443         200
6   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.3        443         300
7   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.2        443         200
8   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.1        443         300
9   01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.3        443         90
10  01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.2        80          100
11  01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.1        443         500
```

executing the code below,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", TIMESTAMP_SECONDS, 'Europe/London') AS time,
  ip_address,
  port,
  SUM(bandwidth) AS mbps,
FROM
  dataset1.table1
WHERE
  _PARTITIONDATE = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 0 DAY)  
  AND timestamp > TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL -40 MINUTE)
GROUP BY
  time,
  ip_address,
  port
ORDER BY
  time,
  mbps DESC
```

I get this table,

```
Row time                ip_address          port        mbps

1   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.2        80          200
2   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.1        80          120
3   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.1        80          110
4   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.1        443         100
5   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.1        443         300
6   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.3        443         300
7   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.2        25          200
8   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.2        443         160
9   01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.1        443         500
10  01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.2        80          100
11  01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.3        443         90
```

which is not what I want. Instead, I want this:

```
Row time                ip_address          port        mbps

1   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.2        80          200
2   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.1        80          120
3   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.1        443         300
4   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.3        443         300
5   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.2        25          200
6   01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.1        443         500
7   01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.2        80          100
8   01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.3        443         90
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT time, ip_address, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(port, mbps) ORDER BY mbps DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY time, ip_address
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:20' time, '192.168.10.1' ip_address, 443 port, 100 mbps UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:20', '192.168.10.1', 80, 120 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:20', '192.168.10.2', 80, 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:20', '192.168.10.1', 80, 110 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.2', 443, 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.3', 443, 300 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.2', 443, 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.1', 443, 300 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 13:00', '192.168.10.3', 443, 90 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 13:00', '192.168.10.2', 80, 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 13:00', '192.168.10.1', 443, 500 
)
SELECT time, ip_address, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(port, mbps) ORDER BY mbps DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY time, ip_address
-- ORDER BY time, ip_address
```

with result

```
Row time                ip_address      port    mbps     
1   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.1    80      120  
2   01/01/2019 12:20    192.168.10.2    80      200  
3   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.1    443     300  
4   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.2    443     200  
5   01/01/2019 12:40    192.168.10.3    443     300  
6   01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.1    443     500  
7   01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.2    80      100  
8   01/01/2019 13:00    192.168.10.3    443     90
```

Comment: Thanks very much @mikhail-berlyant. How would I select through several millions of lines, as it is in my case? Would I still need to use the `UNION ALL`?

Comment: no - the second query presented to you is for testing. You should use the first query with \`project.dataset.table` replaced by reference to your real table. make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer @mikhail-berlyant! In my case, I have millions of lines, hence I can not use the `UNION ALL` What would be the best way to achieve the same result, but for the millions of rows? I have tried numerous ways, with no concrete results.

Comment: Hi @michail-berlyant, I have managed to get it working, except one small part. Regarding the mbps column, I am having to first the original data I am getting, which is in bytes, to mbps, i.e. incoming_bytes * 8 * 10000 / 1000000 AS mbps. Which means I am having to have the following in place: incoming_bytes *131,072 AS mbps, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(port, incoming_bytes AS mbps) ORDER BY mbps DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].* Problem is, when I do the above, it throws the error Error: Unrecognized name: mbps Any idea how I get the ORDER BY mbps to work in this case? Much appreciated as always!

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I am happy to accept the answer above. I will open a new post for the new question. Thanks!

Comment: appreciate it! looking forward for your next questions :o)

Comment: in that new question  - you should present the query that you have problem with and what exactly problem is  - otherwise chances to get answer are not that big ;o(

Comment: Hi @mikhail-berlyant, new question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/q/54583510/9977920. Any assistance, would be appreciated!

Comment: i will check it when get back to pc :o)

Comment: as I mentioned already - you should present the query that you have problem with and what exactly problem is - otherwise chances to get answer are not that big ;o( – (instead you are just asking us to write query for you from scratch - sometimes this works  - in most cases it does not - because StackOverflow is not a code writing service )